# Laravel get Messaging with Elouqent

Tags: laravel, message, relational

I have three tables and models

1. profile
2. messages
3. users

I have three Models
 1. Profile
 2. Message
 3. Users

```
profile table:    id|user_id|profile_image
messages table:  id|message|user_id|friend_id
user table  : id|name|etc
```

I am getting only messages but I want to get these messages with profile and username.

```
   $chat=Message::where(function ($query) use($id){
       $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('friend_id',$id);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use($id){
        $query->where('user_id',$id)->where('friend_id',Auth::user()->id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Have you defined model relationships? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `relationships` found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

You have to define relationships in the model who owns any amount of other models or viceverse.

Following what you give us in your question, your Models probably should be structured like this:

```
<?php

class Profile extends Model {

   // a profile belongs to an user
   function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

And then, in your `User` model.

```
<?php

class User extends Model {

   // an user has many profiles
   function profiles()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Profile', 'id');
   }

   // an user has many messages
   function messages()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Message', 'id');
   }
}
```

And finally, in your `Message` model.

```
<?php

class Message extends Model {

   // a message belongs to an user
   function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'user_id');
   }

   // a message was sent to one friend
   function friend()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Friend', 'friend_id');
   }
}
```

That's how you make relationships in Laravel, you can found the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) depending of the Laravel version you are using.

Finally, you can use Eloquent like this.

```
Profile::with('user)->get();

Message::with('user')->get();

$message = Message::find(1)->user()->where('etc', 'etc')->first();
```